# add a property to existing state array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array in react State and I need to add a new property called Value.
each time I try to add it creates a new item in the array. what I want is new property need to be added as follows

```
value: ''
```

following is my current code

```
docFieldValue.forEach(element => {
    if(element.value === undefined){
        setDocFieldValus(vals => [...vals,{value:''}]);
    }
});
```

docFieldValue array looks like this.

```
{"docData":{
"fields":[
{"key":"biller_address_line1","type":"STRING","mandatory":false,"validation":null},
{"key":"biller_address_line2","type":"STRING","mandatory":false,"validation":null},
{"key":"biller_city","type":"STRING","mandatory":false,"validation":null},
{"key":"biller_email","type":"STRING","mandatory":false,"validation":null}],}}
```

Comment: can you add the expected result after adding ..

Comment: it's adding new items as `{ "value": "" }` for each item in the array

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `map` the `docFiledValus` and check on each item if the `value` is `undefined` then set it with an empty string.

```
setDocFieldValus(prev => prev.map(i => ({ ...i, value: i.value ?? '' }));
```